# значения int через запятую в одной перменной

Tags: python

есть код небольшой:

```
a = "0,4,53"
for i in a:
    classes = int(i)
```

как сделать чтобы переменная classes не заменялся новым значением, а получилось вот так:

```
classes = 0,4,53
```

значения остались int, но перечислены через запятую. Тип стринг, массив и просто по очереди применять значения - не подходит.

Comment: значения остались int, но перечислены через запятую - список?

Comment: Или список, или кортеж, или никак. ``classes = 0,4,53`` —  это невалидная запись, так не получится.

Comment: `list(map(int, a,split(',')))`

Comment: @Эникейщик очень даже валидная, clasess станет кортежем (0,4,53)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = "0,4,53"
classes = tuple(list(map(int, a.split(','))))
```

значение `classes = (0, 4, 53)` это тоже самое, что `classes = 0, 4, 53`

Comment: `list()` - лишнее, достаточно `tuple(map(int, a.split(',')))`

Comment: спасибо, затупил

Comment: спасибо вам огромное